# Problema en Interfaz de Java "Problematic call in constructor"

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, constructor

En esta parte `NetBeans` marca este error

> "Problematic call in constructor"

```
 public VentanaPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle(VentanaPrincipal);
```

Comment: `setTitle` le envía la variable `VentanaPrincipal` , ¿existe dicha variable? Sí la respuesta es Sí , debería cambiar el nombre de la variable  ya que es igual al nombre de la clase

Comment: Gracias, ese era el error que tenia @Dev.Joel

Comment: @Dev.Joel por que no lo agregas como respuesta y si puedes con una mejor explicación para que se quede como referencia futura.